# What to pass as a NULL value for the options parameter of [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:]

Tags: ios, autolayout

Fairly easy to answer I think: What to pass if I don't want to use the options paramater of `[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:]` Passing `nil`does work but compiler complains about the obvious wrong type (`void*` instead of `NSLayoutFormatOptions` which is a `NSUInteger` typedef). Is it safe to pass 0 when I don't know about the value of the enums used in the framework?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLayoutFormatOptions) you can see that passing 0 is actually the same as `NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing`:

> enum {    /* choose only one of these */ 
>   NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft = NSLayoutAttributeLeft,
>   NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight = NSLayoutAttributeRight,
>   NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop = NSLayoutAttributeTop,
>   NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom = NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
>   NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading = NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
>   NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing = NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
>   NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX = NSLayoutAttributeCenterX,
>   NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY = NSLayoutAttributeCenterY,
>   NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline = NSLayoutAttributeBaseline,
>
> NSLayoutFormatAlignmentMask = 0xFF,
>   /* choose only one of these three */
>   NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing = 0 << 8, // default
>   NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeftToRight = 1 << 8,
>   NSLayoutFormatDirectionRightToLeft = 2 << 8,
>   NSLayoutFormatDirectionMask = 0x3 << 8,
>   };
>
> typedef NSUInteger NSLayoutFormatOptions;

Which is considered the default state, so passing 0 is safe.

Answer (score 1):

Use 0.

Here is a sample from [Working with Auto Layout Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html):

```
NSArray *constraints =
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[button1]-[button2]"
                            options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
```